# dont apply css style if element has a specific class

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have an ordered list:

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

when I hover over an item I want it to have some sort of highlight therefore I have:

```
     #selectable li:hover
 {
        /* some style */
     }
```

with JavaScript I gave those list items the attribute that when clicked they change the style. so if I click on Item 4 for example it will have a red background color.

### now how can I disable the hover style if the element happens to be with the style ckicked (red background)?

In other words I don't want :

```
     #selectable li:hover
 {
        /* some style */
     }
```

to apply on li that are selected... how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override the `hover` style

```
#selectable li.selectedclass:hover{
    /* overriding styles */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The real CSS3 answer to this is the `:not()` selector.

You'd change your existing CSS to the following:

```
#selectable li:hover:not(#selecteditem)
{
  /* some style */
}
```

Unfortunately however, this answer is probably not the one you want, because IE8 and earlier don't support the `:not()` selector.

You *could* use a tool like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com) to add support for this to IE, but frankly, it's hardly worth it for this example, as you can easily add another CSS style to override the other one:

```
#selectable li#selecteditem:hover
{
    /* override styles */
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3:

```
#selectable li:hover:not(.selected) {
 background:red;
```

}

HTML:

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="selected">Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```